# Coordinates of the camera's corner in Libgdx

Tags: java, camera, libgdx

the camera(Orthographic in my case) has the origin at the center. 
is there a way to get the coordinates of the corner in the top left and bottom left?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. You can substract half of viewport size over x and y axis to get bottom left corner coordinates. Right?

Answer (score 0):

From the [libgdx documentation](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/OrthographicCamera.html)

```
   void setToOrtho(boolean yDown);
```

Sets this camera to an orthographic projection using a viewport fitting the screen resolution, centered at (Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2), with the y-axis pointing up or down.